# Unable to click on custom listview, blocksDescendants not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm fairly new to Android programming and tried everything I could I found on SO, but it still doesn't work.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.northcityproductions.androidiosapptransfertest1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:paddingStart="50dip"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidListAdapter.java

```
package com.northcityproductions.androidiosapptransfertest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AndroidListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List<String> androidListViewStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Drawable> imagesId = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
Context context;

public AndroidListAdapter(Activity context, List<Drawable> imagesId, List<String> textListView) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, textListView);
    this.androidListViewStrings = textListView;
    this.imagesId = imagesId;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,
            true);
    TextView mtextView = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView mimageView = (ImageView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mtextView.setText(androidListViewStrings.get(i));
    mimageView.setImageDrawable(imagesId.get(i));
    return viewRow;
}
```

}

Finally, MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //get list of apps
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> applications = pm.getInstalledApplications(flags);
    List<String> applicationsInstalled = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Drawable> applicationIcons = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    //Create map and sort alphabetically
    Map applicationsList = new HashMap();
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : applications) {
        if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            // System application
        } else {
            // Installed by user
            String appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel((appInfo));
            appName = appName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + appName.substring(1);
            applicationsList.put(appName, pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo));
        }
    }
    Map<String, Drawable> treeApps = new TreeMap<String, Drawable>(applicationsList);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Drawable> appMap : treeApps.entrySet()) {
        applicationsInstalled.add(appMap.getKey());
        applicationIcons.add(appMap.getValue());
    }
    //Arrange them in listview
    final AndroidListAdapter androidListAdapter = new AndroidListAdapter(this, applicationIcons, applicationsInstalled);
    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv1.setAdapter(androidListAdapter);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("List");
            adb.setMessage(" selected Item is="+parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            adb.show();
        }

    });
}
}
```

I have tried adding the blocksDescendants code in my activity_main.xml under Listview, and Relativelayout, but that doesn't seem to fix it. I also tried setting the focusable property to false for the imageview and textview but that didn't fix it either.